# Bash regex needs to match a string that is always the same format

Tags: regex, bash

I am writing a script that needs to verify a users input.
The user is prompted to enter a ticket number that is always the same format:

HD0000000000000

That is upper-case HD followed by 13 digits.

I need the input to be verified before the script continues or it could goof stuff up later.

So far I have:

```
read -p 'Please enter the Helpdesk Ticket Number: ' TICKET
if [[ $TICKET =~ HD[\d]{13} ]] ; then
    echo "This ticket number seems to be valid. Be sure to double check!"
else
    echo "This ticket number does not seem to be valid! Be sure to double check!"
fi
```

But no matter what I put in at the prompt, it does not match.

I originally had it matching

`HD[0-9]{13}`

but that gave a pass to anything I put in, even if I enter a single lower-case letter.

What did I do wrong? Anything would be helpful!

This script MUST use nothing but bash builtins as it may run on many different machines that have different util sets.
I am developing on bash 3.00 but this will have to run on bash 2.00 - 3.60

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex matching doesn't work in `2.05b`. If you want to make it more compatible you can use this format instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Please enter the Helpdesk Ticket Number: ' TICKET

if [[ $TICKET == HD[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]] ; then
    echo "This ticket number seems to be valid. Be sure to double check!"
else
    echo "This ticket number does not seem to be valid! Be sure to double check!"
fi
```

Even more use `case` which is POSIX compatible:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Please enter the Helpdesk Ticket Number: ' TICKET

case $TICKET in
HD[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
    echo "This ticket number seems to be valid. Be sure to double check!"
    ;;
*)
    echo "This ticket number does not seem to be valid! Be sure to double check!"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex in bash:

```
 ^HD[0-9]{13}$
```

bash regex engine doesn't support `\d` for digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
^HD[0-9]{13}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/BczZPc-zdF_TCPqb)

make sure you have a start line `^` and end line `$`